# AWS Pricing - low traffic .NET WebApi + postgres + React

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I need your advice from someone who is more experienced. For every new user of AWS, understanding of pricing details is a nightmare and it's quite hard to estimate costs.

I need to deploy low-traffic application with the following stack (+ where I thought it's good to deploy it):

1. .NET Core WebApi (AWS Lambda)
2. React app (S3 static)
3. Postgresql database (serverless v2 Aurora)

I'm a new user so utilizing free tier for now. Already deployed API + database and after 24 hours I was quite surprised that cost of this database was about 1$. I was quite sure that it charges me only when it's in use, so no requests from Web API, no cost. Potentially the issue is that I left on my laptop opened connection in the pgAdmin.

If the cost will be about 30$ only for the database (even with low traffic), probably it's much more cheaper for me to buy some cheap VPS, install needed stuff there and host it.

1. What's your opinion? Can I configure it better to make it cheaper?
2. Is VPS better choose in my case? Is it hard to configure it?

Comment: "If the cost will be about 30$ only for the database (even with low traffic)," it will be at least that much. You're probably better off looking at AWS LightSail.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to switch from RDBMS to DynamoDB and go completely serverless. Because when connecting to Lambda via an RDBMS, you may have connection pooling issues, and which would need the RDS proxy to fix the issue. RDS proxy is again having its own cost. Building a Lambda function that talks with an RDBMS without RDS proxy is a bad idea since it opens up too many connections and may cause problems with your RDBMS server, and may affect other applications that use the same database server.

API Gateway, AWS Lambda, DynamoDB, S3, CloudFront, or Amplify can help you host a low-traffic app for almost nothing.

**Personal opinion:** If you are willing to learn new things, you should try AppSync with DynamoDB utilizing JavaScript resolvers. That is not what you asked for, but it is more cost-effective and faster. It also delivers real-time updates, which is really convenient.